# Extract value from an XMLfile using python based on a specific keyword

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I want to extract values of different nodes if the keyword "cardiovascular" exists in one of the node. Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse(r'G:\My Drive\dru.xml')
for channel in tree.findall('.//drug'):
    if channel.find('indication') is not None:
        comment = channel.find('indication')
        if comment.text is not None:
            if "cardiovascular" in comment.text:
                print(channel.find('indication').text)
                print (channel.find('name').text)
```

I  do not see any errors but I don't see any outcome, either. Although in the xml files I can see the keyword "cardiovascular".
Here is a part of the XMl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drugbank xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca http://www.dru.xsd" version="5.1" exported-on="2018-07-03">
<drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2018-07-02">
  <drugbank-id primary="true">DB00001</drugbank-id>
  <drugbank-id>BTD00024</drugbank-id>
  <drugbank-id>BIOD00024</drugbank-id>
  <name>Lepirudin</name>
  <description>Lepirudi.</description>
  <cas-number>138068-37-8</cas-number>
  <unii>Y43GF64R34</unii>
  <state>liquid</state>
  <groups>
    <group>approved</group>
  </groups>
  <general-references>
    <articles>
      <article>
        <pubmed-id>16244762</pubmed-id>
        <citation>Smythe</citation>
      </article>
      <article>
        <pubmed-id>16690967</pubmed-id>
        <citation>Tardy B,</citation>
      </article>
      <article>
        <pubmed-id>16241940</pubmed-id>
        <citation>ggg</citation>
      </article>
    </articles>
    <textbooks/>
    <links>
      <link>
        <title>Google books</title>
        <url>http://books.google.com/books?id=iadLoXoQkWEC&amp;pg=PA440</url>
      </link>
    </links>
  </general-references>
  <synthesis-reference/>
  <indication>For cardiovascular</indication>
  <pharmacodynamics>Lepirudin </pharmacodynamics>
  <mechanism-of-action>Lepirudin</mechanism-of-action>
  <toxicity>In ca</toxicity>
  <metabolism>Lepirudi</metabolism>
  <absorption>Bioavailability is 100% following injection.</absorption>
  <half-life>Approximately 1.3 hours</half-life>
  <protein-binding/>
  <route-of-elimination>Lepir</route-of-elimination>
  <volume-of-distribution>*</volume-of-distribution>
  <clearance>* 164 ml/min [Healthy 18-60 yrs]&#13;
* 139 ml/min [Healthy 65-80 yrs]&#13;
* 61 ml/min [renal impaired]&#13;
* 114 ml/min [HIT (Heparin-induced thrombocytopenia)]</clearance>
  <classification>......
```

Also, I have to mention that there are multiple `<drug>` nodes in the XML file, and there are multiple `<indication>` nodes in each `<drug>` node

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you may want to use intermediate variables instead of calling   `channel.find('indication')` over and over and over again.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers. Can you please point me to some online tutorials on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help would be to use some library that supports xpath contains queries (seems like you can do it with lxml but etree I think only supports limited xpath queries?), then navigate the tree to whichever node you want to return/access some other value of. Here's an example on line 45 of something someone posted on github here: https://gist.github.com/IanHopkinson/ad45831a2fb73f537a79